# How do I convert pixel coordinates to isometric grid coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, canvas

I didn't have too much trouble figuring out where to place my tiles or finding the tile corners, but I can't figure out the math/formula for determining what grid unit the pixel I'm hovering over belongs to. My grid runs like this:

```
        y0,x0|y0,x1|y0,x2
     y1,x0|y1,x1|y1,x2
  y2,x0|y2,x1|y2,x2
```

With y0,x0 being the top/back and centered against the top edge of the canvas. Tiles are twice as wide as long as usual. I have gotten the offset code to work, so that my mouse pixel coordinate offsets are the same as my tiles, but I'm stumped.

Edit: Sorry for the confusing question. All-night code session fatigue.

I have this function (simplified here):

```
getTilePixelCoord(x,y)
{
    p.x = S-yH+xH;
    p.y = yM+xM;
    return p;
}
```

That I use to place my tiles. S is the origin point, where 0y,0x is always placed, H is tile pixel height, and M is H/2. What I need is the opposite of this, a getPixelTileCoord(pixelx,pixely); for getting which tile I'm hovering on.

Comment: "I'm stumped" <- Me too! Have you got any relevant code to share with us? What have you tried thus far? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Initial Observations

The isometric tile grid just a regular rectangular grid with the x-coordinate shifted, depending on how many rows there are.

```
Rectangular Grid (y,x)

             v length (L)
          +_____+xxxxx+xxxxx+
          x     x     x     x
No offset>+xxxxx+xxxxx+xxxxx+
          x     x     x     x
          +xx|xx+xxxxx+xxxxx+
          x  |  x     x     x
          +xx|xx+xxxxx+xxxxx+
             ^ height (H)

+: corners
```

Each tile's length edge is `L`px and height perpendicular to that edge is `H`px. The isometric pixel offset per row will be `O`px.

```
Isometric Grid (y,x)

                  V length (L) is the same as above
height     ......+_____+xxxxx+xxxxx+
dependent >_____x 0,0 x     x     x
offset     ....+xxxxx+xxxxx+xxxxx+
(O)        ...x     x     x 1,2 x
           ..+x|xxx+xxxxx+xxxxx+
           .x  |  x     x     x
           +xxx|x+xxxxx+xxxxx+
               ^ height (H) is the same as above

+: corners
```

### Notation

- `t(ty,tx)` refers to the tile vertically located at `ty` and horizontally located at `tx`
- `p(i,j)` refers to the pixel location (in pixels)
- `MAX_Y` refers to the number of tile rows

(All locations are always listed with the vertical component first.)

### Examples

#### Ex. 1

If you count, you'll notice that the corners of `t(0,0)` are located at the following pixel locations:

- `p(0, 3O)`: top left
- `p(H, 2O)`: bottom left
- `p(0, 3O+L)`: top right
- `p(H, 2O+L)`: bottom right

Each of these four points are corners of other tiles as well.

#### Ex. 2

We can see `t(1,2)` as another example. Their corners are at the following pixel locations:

- `p(H, 2O+2L)`: top left
- `p(2H, O+2L)`: bottom left
- `p(H, 2O+3L)`: top right
- `p(2H, O+3L)`: bottom right

#### General Case

For each unit increase in `tx` (from `t(ty,tx)` to `t(ty,tx+1)`), the horizontal pixel location of the corners changes by `L px`.

For each unit increase in `ty` (from `t(ty,tx)` to `t(ty+1,tx)`), the horizontal pixel location of the corners changes by `-O px` and the vertical pixel location of the corners changes by `H px`.

To generalize, the corners of tile `t(ty,tx)` (where the number of rows is `Y_MAX`, so for our example, `Y_MAX = 3`) are at the following pixel locations:

```
p(    ty*H,   (Y_MAX-ty)*O +     tx*L) - top left
p((ty+1)*H, (Y_MAX-ty-1)*O +     tx*L) - bottom left
p(    ty*H,   (Y_MAX-ty)*O + (tx+1)*L) - top right
p((ty+1)*H, (Y_MAX-ty-1)*O + (tx+1)*L) - bottom right
```

You can plug in the above examples to show that these are the correct locations.

### Pixel To Tile

#### Vertical Location

For a tile `t(ty,tx)` and `p(i,j)`, `ty*H <= i < (ty+1)*H`.

```
ty*H <= i   < (ty+1)*H
ty   <= i/H < ty+1
ty = floor(i/H)
```

Thus, `ty = floor(i/H)`.

#### Horizontal Location

The horizontal location is a little more complex because the offset, and thus the horizontal location, depends on the vertical location of the pixel. We can see that the offset starts at `O*Y_MAX px` at the top and decreases linearly to `0`px at the bottom.

At the top of tile `t(ty,tx)` and pixel `p(i,j)`, `(Y_MAX-ty)*O + tx*L <= j < (Y_MAX-ty)*O + (tx+1)*L`.

At the bottom of tile `t(ty,tx)` and pixel `p(i,j)`, `(Y_MAX-ty-1)*O + tx*L <= j < (Y_MAX-ty-1)*O + (tx+1)*L`.

The difference between the two is linear, totaling `O px`.

To find out far we are down the tile, we can use `frac(i/H)`, the fractional part of `i/H`. For example, at `p(80,0)`, if each tile has a height `H=30`, we would be `frac(80/30) = 20 px` relative to the top of the tile; in other words, two-thirds of the way down. We see from above that `ty` is `floor(i/H)` is actually the integer part of `i/H`. Thus, `ty+frac(i/H) = i/H`.

---

Thus, for tile `t(ty,tx)` and pixel `p(i,j)`, `(Y_MAX-i/H)*O + tx*L < j < (Y_MAX-i/H)*O + (tx+1)*L`

```
(Y_MAX-i/H)*O + tx*L <= j                     < (Y_MAX-i/H)*O + (tx+1)*L
tx*L                 <= j-((Y_MAX-i/H)*O)     < (tx+1)*L
tx                   <= (j-((Y_MAX-i/H)*O))/L < tx+1
tx = floor((j-((Y_MAX-i/H)*O))/L)
```

Thus, `tx = floor((j-((Y_MAX-i/H)*O))/L)`.

### Solution

For any point `p(i,j)`, the tile `t(ty,tx)` is at **`t(floor(i/H),floor((j-((Y_MAX-i/H)*O))/L))`**.

### Your Specific Case

For your purposes, `L = 2H` and `O = H` are likely parameters; taking the above solution and replacing `O` and `L` would reduce the result down to one dependency `H`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know my post was unclear; I'm really having some trouble understanding the math in this. I have this function (psuedo'd):

Comment: Sorry I'm getting the hang of this system. See function in the edited question. Do these solutions give me pixel to grid or grid to pixel?

Comment: @DanieClawson: This is pixel to grid. I'll edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: @DanieClawson: Let me know what you think!